# Set Manifest PlaceHolder for AAR in another AAR

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to wrap an Android AAR, that requires a manifest placeholder be set in an APK, in another AAR.  I would like to set the placeholder value in the build.gradle of the wrapping AAR but the manifestplaceholders list does not seem to apply.

Is this possible?

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @yugico unfortunately I took another route since I couldn't figure it out

Comment: :( Thanks. Will search another way.